# Is there a route for destroy method?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Can anyone tell me if there's a route for destroy method? I'm trying to delete my records in table but when I hit the Delete button is says my route is not define I think that's why my delete action won't work.

> Route [result.destroyEmployee] not defined. (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\account\search.blade.php)

Routes

```
//READ
Route::get('/search',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@getEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.search',
]);


//EDIT
Route::get('/edit/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@editEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.edit',
]);
```

I passed the `id` in the edit routes so it will identify who id is currently in action.

Controller:

```
//READ
public function getEmployee()
{
    $result = DB::table('users')->get();

    return view ('account.search')->with('result', $result);
}


//EDIT
public function editEmployee($id)
{
    $result = User::find($id);

                                        //key     //value
    return view ('account.edit')->with('result', $result);
}

//DELETE
public function destroyEmployee($id)
{
    $result = User::destroy($id);

    return redirect()->route('account.search');
}
```

search.blade.php

```
@foreach ($result as $row)
    <tr class = "success">
        <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->middle_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->username }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href = "{{ route ('account.edit', $row->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>

            <a href = "{{ route ('result.destroyEmployee', $row->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.edit', $result->id) }}">

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "email" class = "control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->email }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->username }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Save</button> 

</div>

<input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "{{ $result->id }}">
<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Comment: Well, I don't see any route pointing to `destroyEmployee` method. That's what the error says.

Comment: @VishalSh Do I need to create a route for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this route in your `routes.php`. I don't encourage delete operation in a GET request, but since you have the operation defined on anchor tag, it will be a GET request.

```
//DELETE
Route::get('/destroy/{id}',
[
    'uses' => 'AccountController@destroyEmployee',
    'as' => 'result.destroyEmployee',
]);
```

You don't have this route defined and you are trying to hit it on clicking `Archive` button

Comment: Why you don't encourage in GET method? Can you provide some example for POST method?

Comment: the action is causing DELETE in database and an ideal REST call for this operation is DELETE request. You will have to change anchor tag to a button tag and add `onclick` method to send AJAX call for any request apart from GET. (You can always use forms though)

Comment: So if the operation is not assigned within a tag. Lets say the action is inside the button so this will be a POST request and still DELETE in database right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It will not be a POST request unless you configure your ajax call to make a POST request. A simple replace of `<a>` to `<button>` wont make a request at all. You need to bind onclick function to it and build your AJAX request in that method.

Comment: According from what I read POST is safer than GET request. So can I use POST request using destroy method? If can I use what changes should I need to do?

Comment: Yes you can. `POST` or `DELETE` any of these are fine

Comment: But it says `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` How can I do this using Request method than passing `$id` to the parameter? Appreciated your tips and time :)

Comment: You are getting that exception because the route right now is `Route::get` change it to `Route::post`, for remaining things, laravel documentation is pretty clear. Please refer that.

Comment: That may be because of the way you are calling the route. You should really be looking at the documentation